# How to separate messages to third party binders in jsmpp

Tags: java, sms, smpp, jsmpp

I am developing an sms gateway using jsmpp library.

This is my scenario.

I bind to the **SMSC**(telecoms company) on 2 connections and receive messages on 2 shortcodes, say 30002 and 30003 , assigned to me by the **SMSC**.

Then, **third party binders**(companies involved in bulk sms push) who normally should bind directly to the **SMSC** bind to my gateway via **SMPP** connections to my **SMPP** server(which serves as an **SMSC** of sorts to them)

The **third party binder** sends messages to the **SMPP** server and I capture this messages, queue them and send them to the main **SMSC**(telecoms company).

The telecoms company then responds with **delivery reports** and messages from the bulk message reports and other data which I forward to the third party binders.

This scenario has worked well for when I have only 1 **third party binder**.

But now we want to handle a more general case where we have many **third party binders**.

Since I have only 2 **short codes** available on which the **SMSC** forwards messages to me, how do I know which of the third party binders owns the **SMSC** response?

I have the unsavoury and inefficient option of forwarding the responses to all connected third parties.

The only other option apart from the above is to get a different **short code** from the **SMSC** for each **third party binder**, which is not cost efficient for my scenario.

Comment: Please clarify, do you need to forward mobile-originated messages (as in "subscriber sent `test123` to 30002") or just delivery reports to third parties? Also, mention which packet types do your third parties use and which do you use with telecom SMSC (submit_sm, data_sm, ... ?)

Comment: I am forwarding MO's and dlrs to the third party. The third party pushes their messages to me with submit_sm and I forward these messages to the SMSC with jsmpp's submit methods. I get DLR's and MO's from the SMSC in onAcceptDeliverSm method and forward them to the third parties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can pretty easily forward all DLRs to the correct third parties. In order to do so, you will have to store some extra data in a database of your choice (if you only have 1 application node and low traffic, even SQLite will suffice; otherwise look towards some NoSQL solution):

1. Every time you receive a submit_sm_resp packet from telecom SMSC, start storing a pair (key-value, actually) `message_id -> third_party_id`.
2. Every time you receive a deliver_sm packet from SMSC, retrieve the `message_id` from the packet, then look for this `message_id` in your DB to find which third party to forward it to.
3. Consider removing the `message_id -> third_party_id` pair after you have successfully forwarded the final DLR for that `message_id`.

---

The situation is a lot worse with the MO messages. The only possible (but nonetheless very bad) way of using a single shortcode for multiple clients (third parties) is having a fragile combination of TTLs and timeouts on you data. It also only makes sense when every MO that you expect is a reply to a previous MT message.

1. Separate incoming MTs that need reply from the receiver using `TLV` or extra `SMPP links`. Let us call those MTs `Questions`.
2. Handle `Questions` something like this: 
   [image: MT]
3. Handle MO messages (`Answers`) like this:
   [image: MO]

### UPD. Text elaboration

In order to know the correct third party for MO message (not delivery report) you need some additional info about who the message is addressed to. This info might originate from either the third party or the subscriber (one who has initiated the MO message in the first place). My diagrams formally describe the case where the third party gives you this information.

1. A third party sends you an MT message that they expect to be `Answered` by the recipient.
2. You make a note in the database, that if the recipient sends you an MO message in the next N minutes, then this `Answer` should be forwarded to the aforementioned third party.

---

I apologise that my answer is not specific to `jsmpp` but I have little knowledge of this library, however, I also believe it should be fairly easy to implement an algorithm once you understood it regardless of your instrument.

Comment: For a given message that I forward to the SMSC, is the messageId returned by the smsc the same as the messageId that the SMSC sends with the deliver_sm after the message gets to the destination?

Comment: Yes, it is. At least, this is true for every telecom operator that I have encountered. Take notice, however, that messageId and sequenceId is not the same thing.

Comment: If the message ids match then you have pretty much solved the problem for messages forwarded to the SMSC. I am trying to see how your solution applies to MOs and other such messages however. I will accept your answer for your beautiful effort. Thanks a lot.

Comment: But dont you think I should use something like a Map for storing the id pair? Instead of the database suggestion?

Comment: Map sound great, but you will have to store it in some kind of a DataBase. If you leave it in memory, it will be lost once your application stops (for whatever reason: be it a crash or an intended stop). As for the MOs, feel free to ask whatever is not obvious in my solution, I'd be happy to elaborate.

Comment: I don't really get what your diagram describes as per the MOs and MTs

Comment: Thanks. I will go through it again.